# Compare link href with address path for menu state

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on right menu and i want to save that state with compare link `href` tag with address path location.

```
function setNavigation() {
            var path = window.location.pathname;
            path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
            path = decodeURIComponent(path);
      $(".sidebar-menu li ul a").each(function () {
                var href = $(this).attr('href');
                if (path.substring(0, href.length) === href) {
                    $(this).addClass('active-item');
                }
            });
```

**The problem** is that the code not recognize similar addresses in one `ul`

for example both of below item give `active-item` class.

```
href="site/city/company/"
href="site/city/company/sample"
```

also here is my html

```
 <li><a href="/Panel/Place" class="active-item"></a></li>
 <li><a href="/Panel/Place/item" class="active-item"></a></li>
 <li><a href="/Panel/Place/City"></a></li>
 <li><a href="/Panel/Definitions/Attribute">/a></li>
 <li><a href="/Panel/TouristDestination"></a></li>
```

Comment: if path points to  : `/Panel/Place` do you want all the `li` elements containing rhis path get that  class or only the `li` which has href same as path.

Comment: So what is your problem? You only want the path that matches the closest to have the active class?

Comment: If I undestood it, you just want the actual page link in the menu rendered as "active link". There is an alternative method just with css: the "target" pseudoselector. e.g. .sidebar-menu a:target {background-color:#888}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Correct : `$(".sidebar-menu li ul a")` to `$(".sidebar-menu ul li a")`
2. I have changed the path matching method, check it out:

```js
//sample path
var root_path = "www.xyz.com/";

function setNavigation(path) {
  path = path.substring(path.indexOf("/"), path.length);
  path = decodeURIComponent(path);
  $(".sidebar-menu ul li a").removeClass('active-item');
  $(".sidebar-menu ul li a[href='" + path + "']").addClass('active-item');
}

$("a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});

$("#navigate").click(function() {
  var path = root_path + $("#path").val();
  setNavigation(path);
});

$("#navigate").click();
```

```css
.active-item {
  color: #eee;
  background-color: #0095ff;
}
ul {
  width: 80%;
}
li {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  padding: 5px;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="center">
  <p>
    <b>Path :</b> 
    www.xyz.com/
    <input id="path" value="Panel/Place/item"/> 
    <input type="button" value="Navigate" id="navigate"/>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="sidebar-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/Panel/Place">/Panel/Place</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Panel/Place/item">/Panel/Place/item</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Panel/Place/item/City">/Panel/Place/item/City</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Panel/Definitions/Attribute">/Panel/Definitions/Attribute</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Panel/TouristDestination">/Panel/TouristDestination</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice compact solution!

Answer (score 3):

You can try [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method:

```
if (href.indexOf(path.substring(0, href.length)) !== -1) {
   ...
```

Example:

```js
function setNavigation() {
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
    path = decodeURIComponent(path);
    path = '/Panel/Place'; //tmp solution
    $(".sidebar-menu li ul a").each(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (href.indexOf(path.substring(0, href.length)) !== -1) {
            $(this).addClass('active-item');
        }
    });
}
setNavigation();
```

```css
.active-item {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/Panel/Place">/Panel/Place</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Panel/Place/item">/Panel/Place/item</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Panel/Place/City">/Panel/Place/City</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Panel/Definitions/Attribute">/Panel/Definitions/Attribute</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Panel/TouristDestination">/Panel/TouristDestination</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Radian I've made an mistake, it should be `if (href.indexOf(path.substring(0, href.length)) !== -1) {`